# Keep jquery dialog in center of mobile viewport when zoom in/out?

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, position, jquery-ui-dialog

I’m trying to make the jquery dialog center of the mobile viewport specifically iphone’s safari, but when users try to zoom in the page the dialog moves at the right bottom part of the page and that makes it not visible anymore.

Here is the code:

```
//-- The dialog
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal:true,
    draggable:true,
    resizable:false,
    width:650,
    height:330,
    cache:false,
    position:'center'
}); 

//-- Make dialog center when page resize 
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("option", "position", "center");
});
```

This works perfectly in PC's browser, but for mobile it only works when page is zoom out.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's sounds like a problem with jQueryUI.

Have you tried a CSS alternative such as this:

JS

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal:true,
    draggable:true,
    resizable:false,
    width:650,
    height:330
});
```

CSS

```
.ui-dialog {
    left: 50% !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    margin-left: -325px !important; // half 650
    margin-top: -165px !important; // half 330
}
```

I've used !important to override the default values defined in the jQueryUI CSS file.